# Wordpress - Is using wp_mail function a sufficient way of sending emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using wordpress and wish to create a custom php script instead of using a plugin for the contact form.

I want to know if using the `wp_mail` function is the same as the php `mail()` function because my host sometimes has issues sending the mail without sending it via the smtp server.

I've always used something like `php_mailer` for my contact forms but am new to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) is not the same thing as `mail`, but by default it does use `mail` to send emails.

In fact, `wp_mail` already uses `phpmailer`. From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init):

> The wp_mail function relies on the PHPMailer class to send email through PHP's mail function

If you wanted to, you could use the [`phpmailer_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init) action to pass arguments to `phpmailer`.

---

You should avoid using `mail` or other libraries *directly*, to send out email. `wp_mail` is [pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), so you can install a plugin to override it, or use your own mailer. There are several plugins that allow you to use external SMTP servers via `wp_mail`.

Comment: So if I used the wp_mail() function and used the phpmailer_init function that will send the email via SMTP?

Comment: @jezuitazus Yes, you can use the `phpmailer_init` action to specify an external SMTP server. If you look at the [example in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init#Examples), that's exactly what it does.